# detectChanges leads to angular performance issue

Tags: angular, angular10, spartacus-storefront, angular-changedetection

I am working on the Spartacus project and I am using `detectchanges()` method to update the view in angular 10. The code reviewer commented that it causes leads to severe performance issue instead of that they suggesting to use observable.

What is the best practice?

Comment: no....I am Spartacus.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, your reviewer is right. First of all `detectChanges()` method could be used only in components with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` if component rendering with `Default` Change Detection Strategy usage of `detectChanges()` not safe and will harm performance, for sure. Next important point is that you should not call `detectChanges()` without calling `detach()` method before `detectChanges()` - [see official documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges). And last but not least is that in most cases is enough to call `.markForChanges()` method instead of `detectChanges()`. You have to understand that when you call `detectChanges()` you take responsibility of Change Detection algorithm on your self. Be careful with that stuff.